# Work flow creation with liferay

Tags: java, workflow, liferay-6

I want to create a custom multi approval work flow in liferay..please find me some ideas.

- How can i create workflow with my portlet?
- Please provide me the steps.

Comment: The answer you accepted does not answer any of your questions. Strange acceptance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have 1.aperte workflow 2.kaleo workflow 3.BPMN2 activiti workflow options..

Comment: -1 Does this really answer the question? Where does it say this is the way to create a workflow in the portlet? Where are the steps? The answer just lists down possible workflow engines.

Answer (score 0):

check below link,you need liferay development studio(IDE)

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen08-designing-workflows-with-kaleo-designer-for-java-0

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer Aperte Workflow for its simplicity.

Here is the link that will describe how to integrate Aperte in liferay,
http://rupalchatterjee.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/integrate-aperte-workflow-in-liferay-6-1/

Here is the link that show how to create a simple workflow in Aperte,
https://github.com/bluesoft-rnd/aperte-workflow-core/wiki/Sample-process-with-Aperte-Modeler